# Compressed Ratio for each Quality in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I Have This Questions :

1-Read the image (‘lena_gray.jpg')

2-Write the image to the disk for quality=[0 5 15 25 50];

3-Find the compression ratio for each value of quality

*I solved the first and second question

*But when I wanted to solve the last question, I did,

a)I calculated the original image size
"OriginalFileSize"

b)I calculated the size of the compressed image "CompressedFileSize" for each Qulaity But when I
calculate the "compressionRatio=OriginalFileSize/CompressedFileSize" for each Quality, I get the same
result even though the quality is different

*What is correct and how can I solve the question ?

*Is there another way to solve the 3 questions?

```
    figure 
    Original=imread('lena (1).jpg')
    imshow(Original)
    information = imfinfo('lena (1).jpg')
    OriginalFileSize=(information.Width*information.Height*information.BitDepth)/8
    //for Quality 1
    imwrite(Original,'CompressedQuality1.jpg','jpg','Quality',0)
    CompressedFileSize1=information.FileSize
    CompressedRatio1=OriginalFileSize/CompressedFileSize1
    //for Quality 5
    imwrite(Original,'CompressedQuality2.jpg','jpg','Quality',5)
    CompressedFileSize2=information.FileSize
    CompressedRatio2=OriginalFileSize/CompressedFileSize2
    //for Quality 15     
    imwrite(Original,'CompressedQuality3.jpg','jpg','Quality',15)
    CompressedFileSize3=information.FileSize
    CompressedRatio3=OriginalFileSize/CompressedFileSize3
    //for Qualoty 25
    imwrite(Original,'CompressedQuality4.jpg','jpg','Quality',25)
    CompressedFileSize4=information.FileSize
    CompressedRatio4=OriginalFileSize/CompressedFileSize4
    //for Quality 50
    imwrite(Original,'CompressedQuality5','jpg','Quality',50)
    CompressedFileSize5=information.FileSize
    CompressedRatio5=OriginalFileSize/CompressedFileSize5
```

Comment: You’re not getting the size of the files you create, you use the input file size over and over again. You need to retrieve the file information for your new file every time. Also, your original input file is already compressed. You need to compare to the uncompressed size to get the compression ratio. Assuming 8-but data, `numel(Original)` is the number of bytes in the uncompressed image.

Comment: @Cris Luengo How can i get the size of the Original Image ?                                               and can you tell me another way to solve this 3 Questions ?                                                    is by numel(Original) ?

Comment: Sorry, your `OriginalFileSize` is good. It should be the same as `numel(Original)` if it’s 8-bit data. But you need to add a `imfinfo()` call after each `imwrite` to learn the size of the file you just created.

Comment: @Cris Luengo  Can you help me if i can solve this Question by for loop ?